# Is it possible to let my app start when Apple TV starts?

Tags: tvos, kiosk

I'm wondering if apple allows configuring apple tv for kiosk/digital signage mode, means - let my app always start on system start. 
I do not yet have the hardware to try, so I'm asking in advance does it makes sense to try?